# Using (:send) in Ruby with keyword arguments?

Tags: ruby

I have a private method that I am trying to use #send to in Ruby to do some testing. The method is complicated and I don't want exposed outside of the class and so I want to test the method but I also don't need to list it as a public method. It has keyword arguments. How can I use `send` to call the method but also pass it keyword arguments/named parameters? Is there a way?

The method looks like this:

`def some_method(keyword_arg1:, keyword_arg2:, keyword_arg3: nil)`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Depends on how the keyword args are defined.

If they're defined inline for whatever reason, pass them inline:

```
SomeClass.send(:some_method, {keyword_arg1: 'foo', keyword_arg2: 'bar'})
```

If they're defined in a hash, you can unpack it instead:

```
hash = {keyword_arg1: 'baz', keyword_arg2: 'bing'}
SomeClass.send(:some_method, **hash)
```

Comment: Note that in Ruby 3.0 you MUST use the double splat operator.
`obj.send(:some_method, **{arg1: 'foo', arg2: 'bar'})`